# Python - package can not import subpackages when installed with setup.py

Tags: python, module, package, setup.py

I developed a python package which I want to use in another project. 
The package structure looks like the following example:

```
- foo
  - setup.py
  - README.md
  - foo
    - __init__.py
    - main.py
    - bar.py
    - sub_pkg1
       - __init__.py
       - example.py
    - sub_pkg2
       - __init__.py
       - example2.py
```

The `bar.py` File contains the `Bar`-Class which relies on the files in `sub_pkg1` and `sub_pkg2` which are imported like

```
from sub_pkg1 import example.py
```

The `__init__.py` files just import each python file in it's directory.
For example the `__init__.py` of `sub_pkg1`:

```
from example import ExampleClass
```

The `main.py` File just imports the Bar Class and executes some methods of it.

```
from bar import Bar
bar = Bar()
bar.foo()
```

The `setup.py`file looks like the following:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='Bar',
    version='0.0.7',
    author='me',
    packages=find_packages()
)
```

When I run the `main.py` file directly from the package it works like a charm.
However when I install it in my other project with pip using the command:
(I don't want to publish the package to PyPi yet and just want to include the development-version in my other project)

```
pip install -e /path/to/package
```

and try to import it - I am getting the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'example'
```

Do I need to export the sub_packages somehow?

I use Python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `from sub_pkg1 import example.py` use `from sub_pkg1 import ExampleClass`

as in `__init__.py` of sub_pkg1 and sub_pkg2 you have already imported `ExampleClass` and you are now free to directly import `ExampleClass` from sub_pkg1 anywhere in your project.

Read more about `__init__.py` and modules here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html